# Samsung Device issue on Share any content Hide statusbar in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, layout, share, samsung-mobile

I have an issue with Samsung device in run flutter app and share
any content with any package like share_plus or flutter_share
show bottom in show all sharable app like WhatsApp , Discord , Telegram etc
but Hide or overlay status bar.
How to fix it

```
i have used this package and try it.
Share_plus : await Share.share('https://www.google.com',subject:'Google');

flutter_share : await FlutterShare.share(
  title: 'Product share', 
  text: 'Mobile',
  linkUrl: 'https://www.google.com'
);
```

issue video link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1frclxs04ffPDJWcGKGPyciWzS8vf_IhC/view?usp=sharing